# After restart OSX 10.9.2 Mavericks starts apps that were closed before restart

Tags: macos, applications, restart

For example just now I quitted all applications and performed a reboot, however, all applications were re-launched after restart even some of those that were closed long before restarting (maybe 12 hours ago in the same session). Is this normal behavior or a bug?

Comment: I would call it a Bug, but then you might have changed a setting somewhere.

Comment: There are a couple of things you might want to check. First, are you making sure that "Reopen windows when logging back in" is unchecked? Second, check the startup items for your user account. Open System Preferences and navigate to the "Users & Groups" panel. Click the login items tab and check to see if the apps that have been giving you problems are checked. If they are, there's your problem. Also, which apps are giving you problems? Is it a specific set of them?

Comment: Could you check what is in your "StartupItems" folder in the Library before restart.

Comment: This bug is still present in 10.9.5. **Reopen windows when logging back in** is off and I know what's in my login items.

Comment: @megadroid Updating to Yosemite fixed it, however, I can’t recommend it since the UI is somewhat sluggish and Mail.app has some serious bugs. Better wait for 10.10.2 which should be released soon.

Comment: @mcb Thanks for the follow-up. I think Mavericks has more than a handful of bugs that Apple will never care to fix but yes, I agree it's too soon to upgrade to Yosemite. Apple is releasing new OS Xs too quickly so I think I'll wait a couple more years and ignore these (rather annoying) bugs. If Apple releases a new OS X next year, no one will care about Yosemite bugs being fixed either.